Space state representation from given differetial equation
I have the ODE:
$\ddot{\alpha}+4\dot{\alpha}+3\alpha=2u-\dot{u}.$
Define $y=[\alpha\ \ \ \dot{\alpha}]^T$. Find $A,B,C,D$ such that:
$$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$$
$$y=Cx+Du$$
When $y=\alpha$, I get:
$$A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    -3 & -4 
  \end{bmatrix}
     ,B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}
  ,C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 &-1
  \end{bmatrix}
,D=0.
$$
But now I'm stuck on the case where $y=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha   \\ \dot{\alpha }
  \end{bmatrix}$. Can I get any help?

Hello, I'm a little confused by the first sentence: You define $y=\left[\matrix{\alpha\ \dot{\alpha}}\right]$, but then you also define $y=\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ a few lines later. Could you clarify? Also, what are $x$ and $u$ supposed to be?

in the case of y=a there is one output(which I solved) ; and for the second there are 2 outputs

No, what I'm saying is that you define $y$ as being a vector and a scalar. That's an "illegal"/illogical mathematical statement. Do you have the original question from a textbook or something that you can show? The information you present isn't giving enough context for me, unfortunately.

1)Convert the equation to the state space representation by decreasing it`s order. Find
the State space Matrixes A,B,C,D. while y is the input angle α.

find the matrixes C,D for the case of y [α α']^T


Is this coming from a textbook? (I can find it online somewhere.) It would be helpful for me to see what exactly is written.

Combine the highest derivatives of both sides, reduce their derivative order by their common maximal amount (= minimum of the orders), thus define $\beta=\dot\alpha+u$. Then, eliminating $\alpha$,
$$
\dot \beta +4\beta =\ddot\alpha + 4\dot \alpha + \dot u + 4u = 6u - 3\alpha
$$
This gives a $2\times 2$ system for the vector $x=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\dot \alpha\\\dot\beta\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-3&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\6\end{bmatrix}u
$$
The reconstruction is then simply $y=x-\begin{bmatrix}0\\u\end{bmatrix}$.

This is of course not the unique solution, one could also set $\beta=\dot\alpha+3\alpha+u$ or other variants. This gives
$$
\dot \beta + \beta = \ddot\alpha+4\dot\alpha+3\alpha+\dot u+u=2u
$$
or as system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\dot \alpha\\\dot\beta\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-3&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\2\end{bmatrix}u
$$
etc.

As to the method presented in the question and the specific question about it: The equation can be written in operator algebra as
$$
(D^2+4D+3)\alpha=-(D-2)u.
$$
Now if we could write $\alpha = -(D-2)\beta$, and we can as this is a linear DE for $\beta$ with (at least) continuous forcing $\alpha$, then in
$$
(D^2+4D+3)(D-2)\beta=(D-2)u
$$
the common factor can be canceled resulting in
$$
(D^2+4D+3)\beta=u.
$$
Read in reverse this gives a constructive method to solve the original equation without having to deal with the derivative of the control $u$.

Now in aiming to incorporate initial conditions into this construction one also has to handle the derivative of $\alpha$. Per parametrization and the just derived defining equation for $\beta$ this gives
$$
\dot\alpha = -D(D-2)\beta =-(D^2+4D+3-6D-3)\beta = -u+3(2D+1)\beta.
$$
Writing $x=\begin{bmatrix}\beta\\\dot\beta\end{bmatrix}$ this gives indeed the system representation
$$
\dot x = \begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\-3&-4
\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}u
\\~\\
y=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\dot\alpha\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
2&-1\\3&6
\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\-1
\end{bmatrix}u
$$
and for the initial values
$$
x(0)=\begin{bmatrix}\beta(0)\\\dot\beta(0)\end{bmatrix}
=\frac1{15}\begin{bmatrix}
6&1\\-3&2
\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha(0)\\\dot\alpha(0)+u(0)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
